# Calling SQL rollback on php exception

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Consider the following scenario:

- I open a new connection to MySQL, using mysqli extension
- I start a transaction
- I do some queries on the MySQL database and to some php computation
- Either MySQL or php may throw some exceptions
- I commit the transaction

(pseudo) code:

```
$sql = new mysqli();
...
{ //some scope
    $sql->query("START TRANSACTION");
    ... 
    if (something)
        throw Exception("Something went wrong");
    ...
    $sql->query("COMMIT"); // or $sql->commit()
} //leave scope either normally or through exception
...
$sql->query( ... ); // other stuff not in transaction
```

If all the above is in some big `try catch` block (or perhaps even the exception is uncaught) the transaction will remain unfinished. If I then try to do some more work on the database, those actions will belong to the transaction.

My question is: is there some possible mechanism that would permit me to automatically send `$sql->rollback()` when I leave the transaction-creating scope in an abnormal way?

---

Some notes:

- [`mysqli::autocommit`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.autocommit.php) is not the same as a transaction. It is just a setting for autocommit you turn on or off. Equivalent to MySQL `SET autocommit`.
- [`mysqli::begin_transaction`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.begin-transaction.php) is not documented and I don't know what is its precise behavior. Will it call `rollback` when the `mysqli` object dies for example?

Comment: If you never commit then essentially it is rolled back after a set period of time by mysql. It essentially is never committed.

Comment: The problem may be some other queries performed on the `$sql` object that may be invoked after the exception has been handled. At that point, I don't know if I am in the transaction mode or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot *automatically* rollback on exception, but with a little code you can do what you want. Even if you already are in a `try-catch` block you can nest them for your transaction section, such as this:

```
try {
    $sql->query("START TRANSACTION");
    ... 
    if (something)
        throw new PossiblyCustomException("Something went wrong");
    ...
    $sql->query("COMMIT"); 
} catch (Exception $e) { //catch all exceptions
    $sql->query("ROLLBACK");
    throw $e; //rethrow the very same exception object
}
```

Even if you use the most generic `catch Exception`, the actual type of the exception is known. When you rethrow, it can still be caught by `PossiblyCustomException` later. Thus, all the handling you already have remains unaffected by this new `try-catch` block.

Comment: Also I have seen this very often, I have a concern. What if the commit produces e.g. a "mysql server has gone away"? The rollback will throw a new exception preventing the original error to be thrown. Any comments?

Answer (score 1):

The Command `mysqli::begin_transaction` is the same (object oriented way) as your `$sql->query("START TRANSACTION");`;

There is no way, to auto rollback on exception.

You can only comit, if everything has success. Then it will be a "auto rollback" if not. But this way, you will have trouble very soon, if you have more then one commit.

So your current code is allready very good. I would do it the full OOP way:

```
$sql->begin_transaction();
try {
   $sql->query('DO SOMETHING');
   if(!true) {
       throw new \Exception("Something went wrong");
   }
   $sql->commit();
}
catch (\Exception exception) {
   $sql->rollback();
}
```

You also can write your own Exception:

```
class SqlAutoRollbackException extends \Exception {
    function __construct($msg, Sql $sql) {
        $sql->rollback();
        parent::__construct($msg);
    }
}
```

But you still need to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to either commit the transaction or rollback the transaction if there was a problem, and there are many ways that a problem could occur - either through a mysql error or php throwing an exception. So why not set up a flag at the start of the transaction, set that flag when the transaction ready to be committed, and check the state of the flag when the process is done to see if a rollback is needed?

If you are afraid of globally scoped variables you could use an overly complicated Singleton class or some kind of static variable for this, but here is the basic idea:

```
function main() {
  global $commit_flag = false;
  start_transaction();
  doEverything();

  if ($commit_flag) {
    commit_transaction();
  } else {
    rollback_transaction();
  }
}

function doEverything() {
  global $commit_flag;
  try {
    /* do some stuff that may cause errors */

    $commit_flag = true;
  } catch { ... }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can handle mysql exceptions using DECLARE ... HANDLER Syntax, but I don't find it proper to try to handle them through PHP !

```
BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION  ROLLBACK;
        START TRANSACTION;
          INSERT INTO Users ( user_id ) VALUES('1');
          INSERT INTO Users ( user_id ) VALUES('2');
        COMMIT;
END;
```

More information can be found here :
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/declare-handler.html